# Need Code for HighCharts with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, chart

Working Code -
The code below works. Ensure that the "Month" column contains a number not a string. Covert Jan to 1 and so on.

```
<script src="/sites/ecj2/ECJ268/SiteAssets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/ecj2/ECJ268/SiteAssets/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/ecj2/ECJ268/SiteAssets/highcharts/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/ecj2/ECJ268/SiteAssets/highcharts/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/ecj2/ECJ268/SiteAssets/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/ecj2/ECJ268/SiteAssets/js/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetYearSeries(series, year) {
    var gotOne = false;
    var seriesOptions;

    jQuery.each(series, function (index, dataItem) {
        if (dataItem.name === year) {
            seriesOptions = dataItem;
            gotOne = true;
        }
    });

    if (!gotOne) {
        seriesOptions = {
            name: Year,
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        };

        series.push(seriesOptions);
    }

    return seriesOptions;

}

jQuery(function ($) {

    var CamlQuery = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRefName='Year'/><FieldRefName='Month' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy></Query>";

    $().SPServices({

        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: true,
        listName: "ColumnChartTest",
        CAMLQuery: CamlQuery,
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRefName='Year'/><FieldRefName='Month'/><FieldRefName='Value'/></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: GraphIt
    });

    function GraphIt(xmlResponse) {

        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Sales'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                }
            },
            series: []
        };

        $(xmlResponse.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {

            var seriesOptions = GetYearSeries(options.series, $(this).attr('ows_Year'));

            var month = parseInt($(this).attr('ows_Month')) - 1;

            seriesOptions.data[month] = parseFloat($(this).attr('ows_Value'));
        });
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

}); //docReady  
</script>      
         
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

---

Original Post -
I have limited coding experience-that is the problem. I need a working template for a Highcharts bar graph that contains a series. The data is drawn from a SharePoint list. I have a working one for a Highcharts pie graph. I have looked over the code on this forum, but I have not been able to find a working example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SP.SE!  Highcharts has many demos available at https://www.highcharts.com/demo, including this one for a [basic bar chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic).  I would suggest going there to figure out how to get Highcharts to draw the chart you want, maybe using some dummy data that mirrors what you expect to get out of SharePoint.  Then, if you still need help pulling the data out of SharePoint and feeding it in to Highcharts, come back and ask that question here.

Comment: Programming questions that are not related to SharePoint are off topic here, and getting Highcharts to work is not _directly_ related to SharePoint.  How to get the data out of SharePoint _before_ you feed it into Highcharts is on topic here.

Comment: I thought that this was related to SharePoint in that the data is being pulled from a SharePoint list using SPServices. I have reviewed the demos on HighCharts, but they are using static tables. I need dynamic loads.

Comment: I have working code now. Not sure how to share it here though

Comment: Highcharts uses data that is available to it in JavaScript code. How that data gets into code to make itself available to Highcharts is separate from how Highcharts uses that data to draw the chart. In the case of those demos, yes, that data is made "available" in code by the programmer statically coding the data directly into JS.  You could also read the data from a file, or pull the data from a web service, or pull the data from SharePoint. That's all separate from what Highcharts does with it: what type of chart does it draw? What colors does it use?  What font sizes? etc.

Comment: So if your question is "how do I pull data from a SharePoint list and format it in a way that I can feed it into Highcharts?", then yes, that question is on topic here, because that deals with SharePoint. But once you have that data in code, if your question is "how do I make Highcharts draw a bar graph with red, green and yellow bars?", then that no longer has anything to do with SharePoint, that is only to do with how Highcharts works, and that is not exactly on topic here, that's all I was trying to clarify.  They're two separate steps in the overall thing you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: As far as adding your code - you should see an "Edit" link at the bottom left of your post? Kind of opposite to where your user block is on the right?  You may not have enough rep yet to be able to edit, I'm not sure what is needed.  If you don't see the "Edit" link, you may need to post a new question, and include your code example there.

Comment: Dylan - Thank you.